# Why is A-Frame 0.3.0 resolution low?

Tags: aframe

In A-Frame 0.3.0 on iPhone in VR mode, the resolution is lower than it was with 0.2.0, but with barrel distortion. How can I get full resolution for my scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We bumped the webvr-polyfill which had some issues with iOS. There is currently a bug in iOS Safari related to canvas resizing such that if we had it at full resolution, VR mode would look broken until you turned the phone.

This should be fixed for iOS 10, so we told A-Frame to give it full resolution for iOS 10 Safari.

If you want full resolution  as a workaround (but it will look broken until you turn the phone), set this before A-Frame:

```
window.WebVRConfig = {
  BUFFER_SCALE: 1,
  CARDBOARD_UI_DISABLED: true,
  ROTATE_INSTRUCTIONS_DISABLED: true,
  TOUCH_PANNER_DISABLED: true,
  MOUSE_KEYBOARD_CONTROLS_DISABLED: true
};
```